# Extract a simple one from a nested dictionary and sort out elements based on a condition

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

**The following dictionary is given:**

```
dict_nested = {"A":{"C":100, "D":{"E":100, "F":100}}, "B":200}
```

**The result should look like this:**

```
dict_result = {"C":100, "E":100, "F":100, "B":200}
```

- the result should be 1 Dictionary which only contain the key-value pairs, which its values are from type Integer and not dict.
- the order should be maintained (i dont mean the alphabetical order of the keys)

Comment: make a recursive function that given a dictionary iterates over the elements. if the value is a number append the key/value pair to the result, otherwise call the function recursively passing the dictionary value of the current key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Sembei said, recursion is needed for this case:

```
dict_nested = {"A":{"C":100, "D":{"E":100, "F":100}}, "B":200}

def extract_dict(d1, d2):
    for k, v in d1.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            extract_dict(v, d2)
        elif isinstance(v, int):
            d2.update({k: v})

dict_result = {}
extract_dict(dict_nested, dict_result)
print(dict_result)
```

Output:

```
{'C': 100, 'E': 100, 'F': 100, 'B': 200}
```